# adding Contact/Number into Textview/textfield like default MessageComposer did

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As like my other questions I tried to search for this. But I didn't get anything.
Maybe my path is wrong. Please direct me.

**Here is my Question :** I have a UITextView. In that I am going to add Numbers, Names and contacts.
I want to show each number separately as MessageComPoser did.

[image: Looks Like]

Does anybody know how to make this? 
If my question is not worthy, give me the correct answer then downvote.
(For my questions somebody downvoted without even giving any answer!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer. I don't want to use Three20 library since it is Very difficult to use in my project.

So i Found Awesome [***Link***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263181/1358508). That gives me the answer.
I used this Code It May **HelpFull** To many users, specially for those who Upvoted This question.

[***Exellent Code***](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/thcontactpicker)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using apple's native framework, they didn't provided any controls for doing the same.

You can use the [**TTMssageRecipientField**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.php#_details) provided by [**Three20**](http://three20.info/) framework.

Comment: Midhun MP :thanks for direct me. Let me try it out. But is it possible to add the label inside the textview??